# Angular 2 - click event not working object undefined

Tags: angular, click

I'm working on angular 2 in visual code and for some reason the click event i have does'nt work.

when i click f12 to check the program on the browser i get this error when i click on the button: "TypeError: _co.task is undefined". i dont know what _co.task is so i could find it in my code and try to fix the problam.

my task-list component:

```
export class TaskListComponent {

  constructor(private _taskListService: TaskListServiceService) { }

  btnEnter: string = 'Enter Task';
  task: string;

  Tasks = this._taskListService.taskListItems;

  AddTaskToList(task) {
    this._taskListService.AddToToDoList(task)
  }
```

my task-list service from which i save and load the task list and have the add to the list function:

```
@Injectable()
export class TaskListServiceService {

  constructor() { }

  taskListItems: toDoListItem[] = [
    { content: 'bla bla' },
    { content: "blablabal" }
  ];

   AddToToDoList(task: string) {
     this.taskListItems.push({ content: task })
  }

}

class toDoListItem {
  content: string;
}
```

Template html:

```
<div class="container" id="listContainer">
   <listTitle></listTitle>
  <div>
    <ul class="list-group col-lg-6">
      <li href="#" class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let task of Tasks">{{task.content}}</li>
     </ul>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contentOfTask" [(ngModel)]="taskContent" name="content">
    <button class="btn btn-success" (click)=AddTaskToList(task.content)>{{btnEnter}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: post the template code too

Answer (score 0):

The type error is complaining that task is undefined, when it should be a string. Try to give it an initial value and see if that works. If not check what you are assigning to "task", so in your `AddToToDoList(task: string = "test") {
  console.log(task);
  // now task should be test unless you send it something.
}`

Comment: after opening the project on chrome the error message got a little more readable: "Cannot read property 'content' of undefined". i think it dose'nt recognize 'content'. could it be that i missed something in the service to task-list component ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your template.

```
(click)=AddTaskToList(task.content)
```

should be

```
(click)="AddTaskToList(task.content)"
```

Comment: I've fixed the mistake that you mentioned. after checking the app on chrome the error message got a little more readable: "Cannot read property 'content' of undefined"

Comment: This means that the task that you pass in the function is undefined. I suggest using `(click)="AddTaskToList(task)"` instead of `(click)="AddTaskToList(task.content)"`. Have a console statement in your function to print the value passed. Debugging that will give you more visibility.

Comment: if i change the function from (click)="AddTaskToList(task.content)" to (click)="AddTaskToList(task)" it works and add list item to the list but it is empty. i need the task.content to add the content of the task to the list/

Answer (score 0):

Your template should be,

```
(click)=AddTaskToList(task)
```

and the function should be,

```
AddToToDoList(task: string) {
     this.taskListItems.push({ 'content': task.content });
}
```

Comment: if i change my function in the service to the one you suggested i get an error. it wont recognize the content in task.content. it says: "Property 'content' does not exist on type 'string'

Comment: So task is a string not an object?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a solution to my problam.

at first i thought i need to pass the task.content in the "AddTaskToList()" in the html file.

but then i saw in another project i worked on that i passed what comes in the ngModel. So when i write some task in the input area i want it to add to the task list.

So what i changed in this project is that i took "taskContent" that is in the ngModel and put it in the parentheses of the function "AddTaskToList(taskContent)"

Comment: that is what we also mentioned in the answer! you dont have to post again , better mark the existing answer